# Submit button calling all HttpPost

Tags: asp.net-mvc, forms, devexpress

The desired process flow:

- user fills out a form
- save the form and provide a result view
- on the result view a few hyperlinks providing popup windows to create action
  plans
- the popup's save button should call the appropriate controller
  action
- update the result view according the popup creation success

The problem: both HttpPost actions called when saving the form.

The current code:
The initial form

```
 @using (Html.BeginForm())
    {
        @Html.AntiForgeryToken();
...
   var groupItem = settings.Items.AddGroupItem(grpSet =>
   {
       grpSet.ShowCaption = DefaultBoolean.False;
       grpSet.GroupBoxDecoration = GroupBoxDecoration.None;
       grpSet.SettingsItemCaptions.Location = LayoutItemCaptionLocation.Left;
       grpSet.SettingsItemHelpTexts.Position = HelpTextPosition.Auto;
       grpSet.ColCount = 2;
   });

   groupItem.Items.Add(item =>
   {
       item.NestedExtensionType = FormLayoutNestedExtensionItemType.Button;
       item.ShowCaption = DefaultBoolean.False;
       item.ColSpan = 1;
       item.HorizontalAlign = FormLayoutHorizontalAlign.Center;

       var btnSettings = (ButtonSettings)item.NestedExtensionSettings;
       btnSettings.Name = "btnCreate";
       btnSettings.Text = "Finish and save";
       btnSettings.UseSubmitBehavior = true;
       btnSettings.RouteValues = new { Controller = "General", Action = "A_General", completed = true };

   });
}
```

The result view with the popup:

```
 <div> Display result
@Html.DevExpress().HyperLink(hl =>
                        {
                            hl.Name = "createAP" ;
                            hl.NavigateUrl = "javascript:void(0)";
                            hl.Properties.ClientSideEvents.Click = "function (s, e) { pcCreateAP.PerformCallback(); pcCreateAP.Show(); }";
                            hl.Properties.ImageUrl = "~/Images/AddFile_16x16.png";
                            hl.Attributes.Add("title", "Create AP");
                        }).GetHtml()
 </div>

@Html.DevExpress().PopupControl(settings =>
{
    settings.Name = "pcCreateAP";
    settings.Width = 700;
    settings.AllowResize = true;
    settings.AllowDragging = true;
    settings.CloseAction = CloseAction.CloseButton;
    settings.CloseOnEscape = true;
    settings.PopupAnimationType = AnimationType.Fade;
    settings.HeaderText = "Create Health Action Plan";
    settings.Modal = true;
    settings.PopupHorizontalAlign = PopupHorizontalAlign.WindowCenter;
    settings.PopupVerticalAlign = PopupVerticalAlign.TopSides;
    settings.SetContent(() =>
    {
        Html.Action("CreateAP", "AP", null);
    });
}).GetHtml()
```

And the popup's cshtml also contains a

```
Html.DevExpress().Button(btnSet =>
    {
        btnSet.Name = "btnCreateAp";
        btnSet.ControlStyle.CssClass = "button";
        btnSet.Width = Unit.Percentage(100);
        btnSet.RouteValues = new { Controller = "AP", Action = "CreateAP" };
        btnSet.Text = "Create";
        btnSet.UseSubmitBehavior = true;
    }).GetHtml();
```

Both action got the [HttpPost, ValidateAntiForgeryToken] decoration.
I don't know is it a DevExpress issue or some basic HTML...

Answer (score 0):

You should try to explicitly specify the Controller and Action Method in your first line of the code.

`@using (Html.BeginForm())`  replace with

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("YourAction", "YourController", FormMethod.Post))
{

}
```

Comment: Tried that one, still calling both actions.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to use a different name than the get function in the controller. In my case I've just renamed it to CreateAPSave and now it is not called, when the initial form is saved.